# Access extension data in Dynamics CRM 2015 Online (C#)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online

So we have an extension for our projects in dynamics CRM which holds critical information for us to have other tools export and use to get further information.

[image: Image of extension]

To loop through accounts and contacts I currently do

```
IOrganizationService serviceA = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;
ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(serviceA);

//Loop through all accounts
foreach(var account in svcContext.AccountSet)
{
     Console.WriteLine(account.Name);
}
```

However how could I do this for projects and loop through that data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use serviceA.retrieveMultiple(query) message for retrieve either all records or purticular filter wise records.

query is like , QueryByAttribute or QueryExpression or fetchXML.

Answer (score 0):

you are using Early Bound style, meaning you generated the classes using crmsvcutil.exe command line or a tool.

You will find your custom entity inside the context as well, so if the schema name of your entity is `tsg_Project` you can do

```
foreach(var project in svcContext.tsg_ProjectSet)
{
     Console.WriteLine(project.tsg_Name);
}
```

pay attention that the generated classes use the schema name (where names can contains upper case or lower case letters) and not the logical name, where the names are all lower case.

Comment: A bit late perhaps, but change "account" to "project" in the above code, Guido did the ole copy-paste error this time :)